# In ActiveAdmin, is there a way to display associated nil model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a model Site which includes a foreign key to User, user_id.  All of the sites have a user_id but over time, some of the referenced User elements have been deleted.  My ActiveAdmin index looks like this:

```
index do
  column :domain
  column :user
  column :created_at
  column :updated_at
end
```

The error that I get in the case of a missing user is this:

```
user_name delegated to user.name, but user is nil
```

Is there a way to modify my index method so that it doesn't error out in this situation?

Comment: try this `user.try(:name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this. First is customize the `index` code:

```
index do
  column :domain
  column :user_name do |site|
    site.user.try(:name)
  end
  #...
end
```

[Reference](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html).

Or, you can add `allow_nil` option to `delegate` method:

```
class Site
   delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

[Reference](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate).